# Accessing constant from environment.ts in index page

Tags: angular6

I'm new to Angular technology. I have created one application where I want to customize some visual properties in `index.html` file based on some constant value from `environments/environment.ts` file. I have tried to read that ts file in index.html page  using javascript code but its returning 404 status code for environment.ts file. So my query is, is there any way to access these constants from environment.ts file in index.html page. I have read some article and got to know that Angular app will be bootstrapped after index.html is loaded. Please give suggestions if have any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have got an alternate solution for that problem as, accessing environment file in app.component.ts and setting those properties of HTML element from same component file.